# Problem with python driver in Cassandra when use prepared statements

Tags: python, cassandra, cassandra-driver

when I want to update a set item in Cassandra table with python code like following

```
ps = session.prepare( """ UPDATE test,tbl SET val = val + {'?'} where name = ? and id = ?;""" )
bs = bind(ps, ['name', 'name', 1])
session.execute(bs)
```

I got error

```
Too many arguments provided to bind() (got 3, expected 2)
```

the problem is {'?'} that cant identified by prepared. I test {\'?\'} but nothing change.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your table definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: forgot about that syntax...

You need to use following syntax:

```
UPDATE test,tbl SET val = val + ? where name = ? and id = ?;
```

and bind with set as first parameter:

```
bs = bind(ps, [set(['name']), 'name', 1])
```

Original answer:

You don't need to put quotes around `?` character - when bind happens, it's correctly quotes the text & other types.

P.S. Please note, that if you use `{?}`, this means that you always insert one element into the set. If you need more, then you need to use just `?`, and pass a python set as an argument.

Comment: when I remove quotes form ? I got following error

Invalid set literal for val: bind variables are not supported inside collection literals